# how to automate the snapshot versions in maven 3

Tags: jenkins, maven-3, nexus

I have two projects namely Abc and DEF. Now the project DEF has dependency of the project Abc. Daily we use the run the Jenkins build. The project Abc artifacts will be deployed to the Nexus. The Project DEF has to utilized the latest snapshot from the nexus directory which was created by the project Abc.

I should not change the project DEF pom.xml files every-time to pickup the latest build from project Abc. How can i achieve this automates process.

By the way i used the `buildnumber-maven-plugin` to do the auto version increment in the project Abc.

Comment: please paste your dependency of Abc which is present in DEF.

Comment: The buildnumber-maven-plugin is the wrong way. SNAPSHOT's are the correct way.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have something like this in your pom.xml of DEF

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>some.group.id</groupId>
        <artifactId>Abc</artifactId>
        <version>1.00.000-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

With that, as long as both Abc and DEF are configured as Maven-Jobs in Jenkins, the CI-Server should notice every time a SNAPSHOT for Abc is built and therefore trigger a new build of DEF (unless, of course, somebody beside the CI-Server was building and deploying the SNAPSHOT to Nexus Repository, which shouldn't happen.)

If you want to enforce always using the latest Snapshot from the Nexus Repository you can add Option -U as a Maven Option.

Comment: Better to use the default convention in Maven like **1.0.0-SNAPSHOT** and the scope *compile* is the default so no need to give it explicit.

Comment: But how can i make only the Abc should give me the snapshot version and not others?

Comment: @khmarbaise: I keep forgetting the defaults to things, so I got into the habit of explicitly declaring even defaults in places where I sometimes do use settings that are not default as well :)

Comment: @Mayilarun: I'm not sure I understand your problem. You declare a dependency block like above for every dependency. So you use Snapshot for Abc but the released version for everything else.